# Como pegar os dados de retorno de uma função via ajax?

Tags: ajax, cakephp-2

Eu tenho um ajax na minha view add que faz uma requisição assincrona em uma action test na minha controller, nessa função eu preciso retornar a variável $balance pra minha view add, gostaria de saber como eu faço pra mandar esses dados e como eles chegam na minha view.

Segue abaixo a minha função ajax:

```
    $('#entity').click(function(){
    var campanha = $('#entity').serialize()
    console.log(campanha); 
     $.ajax({
       type: 'post',               
       data: campanha,
       url:'<?php echo Router::url('/emailMarketings/test/'); ?>',
       })
    });
```

E aqui a minha action:

```
    public function test() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $teste = $this->request->data;
    }
    // debug($teste); die;

    // $this->redirect($this->referer());

   $balance = $this->Balance->find('first', array('order' => array('Balance.cota_email=' => $teste['Balance']['campaigns'])));
}
```

Essa é a minha função, gostaria de mandar essa variável pra minha view e imprimir ela lá. Mais não sei como mandar ela pra minha view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No fim desse método `test`, antes de fechar a função, acrescente:

```
$this->set('balance', $balance);
```

Isso deixará uma variável `$balance` disponível na sua view `test.ctp`.

---

No lado do JavaScript, você precisa definir um *callback* que determina o que será feito quando chegar a resposta da requisição. A parte do Ajax fica assim:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',               
    data: campanha,
    url:'<?php echo Router::url('/emailMarketings/test/'); ?>',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Retornados os seguintes dados:');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Eu não tenho uma view test, tenho uma view add, e tenho uma função ajax que me manda pra action test na minha controller, gostaria de saber como retornar essa variável $balance ora minha view add.

Comment: A action test renderiza uma view test (se existir). E isso é o que é mandado de volta para o JavaScript (que suponho estar na view add). Talvez o problema esteja no JavaScript então. Pois é lá que você tem acesso ao resultado da requisição Ajax.

Comment: @DevidyOliviera Você até pode usar uma *action* sem uma *view*, mas para isso você deve informar no *controller* que ele deverá não renderizar automaticamente uma *view* assim `$this->autoRender = false;`

Comment: @bfavaretto Então na minha action se eu colocar o set ele já manda direto pra minha função ajax. Basicamente eu preciso descobrir como pegar esses dados lá. É isso?

Comment: Acho que sim. Não quer editar a pergunta e incluir a parte do JS que faz a requisição ajax? @DevidyOliviera

Comment: @bfavaretto Editei a pergunta.

Comment: @DevidyOliviera Editei a resposta

Comment: @bfavaretto Valeu pela atenção. Muito obrigado.